# clojure classpath + lein question

Tags: clojure, leiningen

here is a very specific question re the clojure class path and lein / emacs

lets say I'm working with a project and have a repl with clojure-jack-in. I need to add a new dependency to this project, is there any way to run lein deps and then be able to use the downloaded .jar in the open repl right away (possibly a repl command?)?

right now whenever I need to add a new dependency I need to reset the swank/slime connection for it to become visible in the classpath.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three options:

- Use Jark to start a REPL on a JVM that can handle new jar files at runtime (http://icylisper.in/jark/index.html)
- add-classpath method in clojure (breaks sometimes ... http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/43a413ae55ed25d0)
- Write your own code to add the new jar file (http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/0095ea6e918c430e)